# How to make image slide show using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slideshow, jquery-slider, jquery-slide-effects

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and jQuery. I'm trying to add a slider to my web page.
So I want to make it look like the slider at http://www.orthoimplantcompany.com/products/
Can any one please give me an idea on how to do this?
I have three products. After click on one product, it should open the image gallery so that the user can see the products.

Comment: That's a grid with a filter, it isn't a slide show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are following js framework

http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-controlnav.html

if you want to go to other page, you need to wrapp IMG tag into A

Answer (score 1):

3rd result on Google: http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/

StackOverflow is about letting us know what you've tried, and asking clear questions around what to do, or why isn't some specific code working.

It's not really a "How do I do this?" site - https://stackoverflow.com/faq

Try out some sliders, give it a go, follow it through and then ask with specific questions if you can't get it working. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting out with JavaScript and jQuery, use one of the freely available plugins that matches what you need, for example [Tiny Carousel](http://www.jsplugins.com/Scripts/Plugins/View/Tiny-Carousel/).

Once you see how the plugins work, you may want to adjust it or write your own from scratch.